# Why is Slick giving me this warning regarding PNG data?

Tags: java, image, png, slick2d

I'm getting this warning in the console:

```
WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
```

After switching between png files, it seems the warning is appearing because I was using a 16 bit PNG image. Why is this? Should I ignore it and stick with 16 bit or use 8 bit?

Comment: As general advice.  Don't ignore warnings.  "Go with the flow" & use 8 bit.

Comment: Or better, patch slick2d to support 16-bit PNGs, and send a pull request to the project.

Comment: Does you `.PNG` load as expected? If so, it's not something that will break you (yet), but ideally you'd want to patch Slick, or at least submit a bug/issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that are Googling this error (like I did), my answer was that my PNGs were interlaced. They would still load, but display the above error. Short answer, switch interlacing to none when you save out of your image editor (I'm using Photoshop CS6).