# Slick giving warnings about PNGs?

Tags: java, slick2d

I am recieving the following error whenever I run my code, using Slick to load a .PNG.  It loads properly but the console outputs a large amount of issues concerning failure to load properly :

```
WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
```

I know there is an article with a similar issue, but not the same.  The solution present was to revert the PNG to a 16 bit file.  I tried this, to no avail.  It also suggested to remove the interlacing.  This also failed.  I know it is loading a PNG file, because I made the console output the file extension.  I also know that the program is loading the texture file properly, since it works.  Is there a reason this warning happens?  By the way, I am using Slick-Util.jar, not Slick2D.  There wasn't a tag for Slick-Util, sorry.

Comment: You get this error and *yet* the image loads? ... I would assume this to be a fatal error. Did you check if a utility such as `pngcheck` reports anything unusual about your input files?

Comment: I will go ahead and make sure my png files are ok

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with them...

Comment: If the other article you refer to is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876968/why-is-slick-giving-me-this-warning-regarding-png-data, then: the suggestion was to switch to *8-bit* images, not to 16-bit.